# Was ist der Unterschied zwischen "vorbeugen" und "verhindern"?

Tags: difference, word-choice, synonym

> **[vorbeugen](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/vorbeugen#Bedeutung2):**
>   etwas durch bestimmtes Verhalten oder bestimmte Maßnahmen zu verhindern suchen
>
> **[verhindern](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/verhindern):**
>   durch entsprechende Maßnahmen o. Ä. bewirken, dass etwas nicht geschehen kann, von jemandem nicht getan, ausgeführt usw. werden kann

Quelle: Duden

Gibt es denn einen Unterschied zwischen den Verben?

Comment: Interessiert dich nur der inhaltliche Unterschied oder auch der in der Konstruktion?

Comment: Mir interessiert beliebiger Unterschied. Ich weiß doch, dass man einer Sache vorbeugt (Dativ) und eine Sache verhindert (Akkusativ)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ja, und du hast diesen Unterschied auch selbst erwähnt:

> Vorbeugen = **versuchen** zu verhindern
>   Verhindern = tatsächlich verhindern

Wenn ich jetzt Maßnahmen ergreife, um Altersdiabetes **vorzubeugen**, kann ich die Wahrscheinlichkeit, daran zu erkranken, senken. Aber ob ich das wirklich **verhindern** kann, werde ich erst in einigen Jahrzehnten wissen.

„Vorbeugen“ hat in der Regel eine betont prophylaktische Bedeutung. Dies lässt auch die Silbe „vor“ erahnen. In der Regel kann man einem Unglück nicht mehr vorbeugen, wenn es schon fast eingetreten ist. Daher würde man normalerweise sagen:

> Verzweifelt versucht der Pilot den Absturz im letzten Moment noch zu verhindern.

Aber:

> Um Überraschungen vorzubeugen, ordnete er lange vor dem Start eine gründliche Überprüfung des Flugzeugs an.

Wegen des präventiven Charakters von „vorbeugen“ ist dasjenige, welchem vorzubeugen ist, regelmäßig spekulativ. Daher zieht man etwa in der Formulierung

> Missverständnissen vorbeugen

dieses Verb vor und erweckt somit weniger den Eindruck Missverständnisse zu erwarten.

Comment: Den Tod kann man definitiv nicht verhindern.

Comment: Ich werde ewig leben, oder bei dem Versuch sterben!

Comment: @null: Das hat auch niemand behauptet.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast was wiederum ich nicht behauptet habe. Werden hier Kommentare gleich als Kritik aufgefasst?

Comment: @null: Nein, ich habe lediglich deinen Kommentar kommentiert. Das war keine Kritik.

Comment: @Ludi: Ich habe deiner Veränderung zwar zugestimmt, aber in Zukunft solltest du beim Editieren nur Fehler ausbessern, oder minimale inhaltliche Veränderungen vornehmen, welche die ursprüngliche Antwort nur marginal verändern. Von der jetzt existierenden Antwort stammt nur das erste Viertel von mir, und der Rest (nämlich alles ab dem Absatz, der mit »*"Vorbeugen" hat in der Regel*« beginnt) ist von dir, dennoch steht unter der Antwort, dass ich sie geschrieben hätte. Stattdessen könntest du eine eigene Antwort verfassen (und würdest dann auch die Punkte für die Bewertung der Antwort kassieren).

Comment: @Ludi: ich sehe, dass du die Antwort ziemlich radikal ausgeweitet hast. In einem solchen Fall solltest du dir überlegen, ob du nicht besse eine eigene, zusätzliche Antwort schreibst.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Vielen Dank. Es ist sehr freundlich von Ihnen, dass Sie an meine Reputation denken. Beim ersten Versuch eine Frage zu beantworten wurde mir vorgeschlagen sie zu editieren. Ich bin noch nicht mit den diesbezüglichen Gepflogenheiten vertraut, will mir jedoch Mühe geben. Aufgrund mangelnder Reputation konnte ich Ihnen übrigens erst jetzt für den Kommentar danken.

Comment: @Takkat Vielen Dank, ich werde mir Muehe geben.

Comment: "Ich nehme ein Medikament um einer Erkrankung vorzubeugen/ um eine Erkrankung zu verhindern" - der Erfolg der Maßnahme steckt nicht in den Wörtern selbst.

Answer (score 1):

"Vorbeugen" ist vorausschauend agieren, um etwas, was vermieden werden soll, nicht eintreten zu lassen.

"verhindern" enthält nicht die Zusatzinformation der frühzeitigen und vorausschauenden Maßnahme.

Comment: "Um ein Überfluten der Altstadt zu verhindern baute die Kommune einen Deich" kann man nicht sagen? "Die rasch aufgetürmten Sandsäcke sollen einer Katastrophe vorbeugen"?

Comment: Natürlich kann man es sagen.  Mit "vorbeugen" wird  ja nur der vorausschauende Aspekt hervorgehoben.

Comment: Jedes Verhindern, das nicht als ungewollte Nebenwirkung eintritt, ist ebenfalls vorausschauend.